# FIND_IN_SET in doctrine 2 with DoctrineExtensions

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

here is my query

```
 $sql = 'SELECT users.userId as userId
      FROM App\UserProjects up
      LEFT JOIN up.user users 
      WHERE up.project = :project AND FIND_IN_SET(:comp, up.company)';
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($sql);
 $query->setParameter('project', 3);
$query->setParameter('comp', 4);
$results = $query->getResult();
```

But this gives me the error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string.

What am i doing wrong?
Is there a work around?
and the field i am searching in has comma seperated values, if FIND_IN_SET is not working, is there any other way i can do the same query?

and i am using this extension
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: Why are you using `find_in_set` ? is the column `up.company` has `csv` data?

Comment: @RavinderReddy up.company column has data like this `1,3,4,5` and i have to search in them with query

Comment: If possible, show us the generated SQL.  Also, is `\U` treated as a Unicode introducer?

Comment: @RickJames It's doctrine query builder query and we have table defined in App\Projects class.  doctrine will translate this query to `SELECT users.userId as userId
      FROM user_projects as users...... FIND_INSET('somevalue',users.company)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` give you the index of the searched element. You have to compare it to something:

```
FIND_IN_SET(:comp, up.company) != 0
```

You should use `IN` instead, it doesn't need any extension

```
AND :comp IN up.company
```

Comment: `:comp IN up.company` gives _Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'up'_
And `:comp IN (up.company)` gives _Expected Literal, got 'up'_

Comment: This will return only one result (the first match, same behaviour in SQL) whereas FIND_IN_SET will return multiple.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the [symfony bundle "wrapper"](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) instead of the library directly, because it will help you to register and use the extension in the correct way.

If you're looking for docs, read [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)

Comment: OP is talking about Berbelei extensions not Stof https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions (very different)